# Why my javascript is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written the following script to change the back color of check box when checked but this is not working on Mozila

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkBoxList1OnCheck(listControlRef)
{
 var inputItemArray = listControlRef.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for (var i=0; i<inputItemArray.length; i++)
 {
  var inputItem = inputItemArray[i];

  if ( inputItem.checked )
  {
   inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
  }
  else
  {
   inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
  }
 }
}
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxList1" onclick="checkBoxList1OnCheck(this);" runat="server">
  <asp:listitem value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="2">Item 2</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="3">Item 3</asp:listitem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and even in page load i add as follows

`CheckBoxList1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxList1OnCheck(this);");`

But still i am unable to work it out in Mozila can any one help me

Comment: What exactly is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: Is not not working in IE or Mozilla?

Comment: I am not getting any errors i am unable to get the output as i required

Comment: @Radu on Firefox IE and Chrome works fine for me

Comment: then you might want to correct that text where you say "not working on IE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Look at the JavaScript error console (CTRL + SHIFT + j), `parentElement` is not supported in Mozilla browsers.

Try using `parentNode` instead:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < inputItemArray.length; i++) {
            var inputItem = inputItemArray[i];

            if (inputItem.checked) {
                //inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';//Won't work in Mozilla
                inputItem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
            }
            else {
                //inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'White';//Won't work in Mozilla
                inputItem.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'White';

            }
```

Comment: A small question if i would like to give a code instead of color how can i

Comment: If you didn't get the color code answer, just replace the color name with the corresponding code e.g = 'red'; -> = '#FF0000';

http://bit.ly/mxtyW2